# Jorge Luis Borges suggests that using a lottery is an "intensification of chance." Does this make sense?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, probability

By intensification of chance, Borges adds that a lottery brings "a periodic infusion of chaos into the cosmos."

To me, the idea that chance can be "intensified" seems strange.  However, I'm also not sure how to operationalize the idea of "intensification."

Can anyone provide some insight into this idea? Thanks!

Comment: First off, welcome to philosophy.se. I'm not really seeing the philosophical content to what you're asking here. A lottery intesifies chance insofar as its results are (ideally) just random. In other words, it draws our attention to the manner in which some things are just luck. But this is just parsing the English. I'm not at all understanding what you mean by "operationalize" here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that story B is suggesting that the lottery in which some become kings, some are executed, etc is an intensification of chance in the sense that makes the normal, chancy events of human life happen more quickly and in a single lifetime rather than over generations. There's nothing specially mathematical or philosophical about it.